# What are good packages for online linear regression besides Vowpal Wabbit?

Tags: stochastic-gradient-descent

Does anyone know of online learning packages that implement NG and NAG algorithms from Stephen Ross' paper: chrome-extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/http://auai.org/uai2013/prints/papers/192.pdf.
I know Vowpal Wabbit is the main package for this but installing python wrapper is not straight forward and the stand-alone command line package is hard to work with due to vw input/output format.( I have spent two days reading related issues for installing the wrapper in stack overflow)